# Parse PFQuery not returning array of all objects in a class

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I am running the query detailed below. It does not log any error and proceeds to log the objects array. When it logs the objects array it displays every object within it up until the first object that was added to the class today. No objects other than the first one added today are displayed. If I delete the first object from today it will display every object up until the new first object for today.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"className"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", objects);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out why this was occurring so I simply created a new class and added all of the values from my old class to it and it began to work.